# Extracting information from entries in a LDIF file

Tags: text-processing

I've a file that contains entries like this:

```
ddn: cn=312548,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312548001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312548999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: something else

dn: cn=312544,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312544001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312544999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: after bike

dn: cn=312542,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312542001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312542999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: pen mark

dn: cn=312539,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312539999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312539001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: used car

dn: cn=312537,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312537001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312537999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: Book bike

dn: cn=312534,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312534999,ou=ServiceAccounts,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=312534001,ou=Unnamed,ou=Identities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
member: cn=fe7316f7-05d6-439b-8b9b-4364f4936615,ou=Named,ou=Identities,ou=Acti
 ve,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: Apple
```

Now I want to know only the dn entries which have a member "Named".

The output should contain the "abcName" and the "dn".

Comment: Please see the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: which entry in your example should be printed ? Could you show an example of the output you desire as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your sample,

```
awk -vRS= -F': *|\n' '/,ou=Named,/{print $2, $NF}' < file
```

would output:

```
cn=312534,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc Apple
```

(that assumes `abcName` is the last attribute in each entry and that `,ou=Named,` may not be found in other attributes or the `dn`, and that the attribute values are not encoded).

To account for LDIF line continuations (where for instance `ou=Named` could become `ou=Na\n med`), you can first remove them:

```
awk -vRS= -F': *|\n' '{gsub(/\n /, "")}; /,ou=Named,/{print $2, $NF}' < file
```

Comment: LDIF can have based64 encoded text, too. Parsing this stuff is horrible. (I know.) Probably easier to ignore that and wait to see if it's a problem to the OP

Comment: @roaima, or use `perl -MNet::LDAP::LDIF`

Comment: Whats GNU in my answer ?(sorry can't ping you on mine)

Comment: @User112638726, check the [edit log](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/211310/revisions). Note that you can always ping editors (though their name are not offered for completion).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Didn't really understand what you meant ? And i didn't know that thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed

```
sed 'H;/^$/{h};/abcName/{x;/,ou=Named,/{s/member:[^\n]*\n//g;p}};d' file

dn: cn=312534,ou=Entities,ou=Active,ou=Vault,o=abc
abcName: Apple
```